# Easiest way to check if current line is "empty" (ignoring whitespace)?

Tags: whitespace

I just want to check if the  current line is empty or not (if it contains only whitespace, then I still consider it empty).

Here is my initial version:

```el
(defun strip-text-properties(txt)
  (set-text-properties 0 (length txt) nil txt)
  txt)

(defun is-current-line-empty ()
  (interactive)
  (setq c-line (thing-at-point 'line))
  (string-match "^\s*$" (strip-text-properties c-line)))
```

What is the easiest way to check if current line is empty?

Comment: In a lisp string, writing `\s` is equivalent to writing `s`. Perhaps you meant `"^\\s*$"`.

Comment: As a general comment, elisp will make more sense once you start thinking in terms of actions on *buffers*, as opposed to (as one tends to do in other languages) doing things with *strings*. Isolating and extracting a string in order to perform some test is likely to (a) be inefficient, and (b) dramatically reduce the number of tools at your disposal. Elisp is *really good* at doing things directly on the contents of buffers.

Comment: @YoungFrog, also it should be `\\s-` instead of `\\s`. That hyphen is required in elisp regexp.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Would something like this be "easier"?

```el
(defun current-line-empty-p ()
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-line)
    (looking-at-p "[[:blank:]]*$")))
```

Comment: Shouldn't `space` be `blank`? (to account for tabs)

Comment: @ideasman42 `space` accounts for all whitespace, not just space characters. That said, `blank` might be better here because it only accounts for horizontal whitespace rather than all whitespace. Reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char-Classes.html#Char-Classes

Comment: `:space:` uses the syntax table, where `:blank:` is simply space or tab, which seems more accurate.

Answer (score 12):

A simple method, close to what you have:

```el
(defun current-line-empty-p ()
  (string-match-p "\\`\\s-*$" (thing-at-point 'line)))
```

Comment: I like this solution because it does not modify `match-data`.

Comment: You need to have `\\s-` instead of `\s`. Have you tried that solution?

Comment: Oddly, I do use it quite a bit. But I just wrote this off of memory. You are correct.

Comment: *still missing the hyphen?* :)

Comment: It was early, and I hadn't completely woken up yet.

Comment: `(thing-at-point 'line)` seems to return `nil` in an empty buffer (or only whitespace in buffer) and then `string-match-p` returns an error as `nil` is not a string. So probably rather use `(buffer-substring-no-properties (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))`.

Answer (score 5):

```el
(defun blank-line-p (&optional pos)
  "Returns `t' if line (optionally, line at POS) is empty or
composed only of whitespace."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (or pos (point)))
    (beginning-of-line)
    (= (point-at-eol)
       (progn (skip-syntax-forward " ") (point)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

`current-indentation` gives you the column following leading blanks, which can be compared against the column at the end of line:

```el
(defun blank-line-p ()
  (= (current-indentation)
     (- (line-end-position) (line-beginning-position))))
```

Comment: Am I missing something or this can be simplified to just `(= (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))` ?

Comment: Ah, nvm, I see, the answer is considering a line with whitespace to be empty as well. Nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another simple solution for it, taken from `comment-dwim-2` package

```
(defun is-empty-line-p ()
  (string-match-p "^[[:blank:]]*$"
        (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position)
                          (line-end-position))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```el
(defun blank-line-p ()
  (and (progn (skip-chars-backward " ") (bolp))
       (progn (skip-chars-forward " ") (eolp))))
```

(Note that the `progn`s are in fact unnecessary because the skip functions never return nil).  As Dan does in his answer, `skip-syntax-*` could also be used instead.

Comment: This does not identify a line containing only tabs as blank. `skip-syntax-*` is the right set of functions to use here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a modification of what PythonNut answered which did not work for me (why?):

```
(defun current-line-blank ()
  (= 0 (string-match-p "^\\s-*$" (thing-at-point 'line))))
```

`string-match-p` returned the index of the next line whenever the current line wasn't blank. So I checked that the return value is 0.

Comment: The index of the next line?   What do you mean exactly? (and welcome on emacs.SE!)

Comment: @JeanPierre `(thing-at-point 'line)` includes the newline at the end of the line. If the current line is not blank, the regexp matches at that newline. The only time `string-match-p` returns nil here is on the last line of the buffer (and Dario, your version doesn't work on the last line if the buffer doesn't end with a newline).

Comment: A better fix would be to match the beginning of the string instead of matching the beginning of any line in the string. I've edited PythonNut's answer.